# why my "host-only" nic on virtualbox refuse the ssh?

Tags: virtualbox, firewall

I made a test machine with old mandrake 9.0 for penetration testing
(had a lot of bugs,so is the ideal).
For security reason i use "host only nic" with virtualbox.
The firewall on machine is disabled but nmap report all port closed except 554!

```
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp   filtered ssh
23/tcp   filtered telnet
135/tcp  filtered msrpc
139/tcp  filtered netbios-ssn
161/tcp  filtered snmp
445/tcp  filtered microsoft-ds
554/tcp  open     rtsp
1433/tcp filtered ms-sql-s
1434/tcp filtered ms-sql-m
```

What can it be?

I try also to accept all machines on /etc/hosts.allow
but no success
I want to ssh the machine from my network
Machine has 10.1.1.2 ip
my network is 192.168.0.0/24
I can ping the machine but no ssh

Comment: RTSP is Real Time Streaming Protocol: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol

Comment: As `root` execute `netstat -tulpan | grep ':554'` on the machine you were testing with `nmap`.

Comment: I know,but my problem is another,I want to ssh the machine

Comment: @elbarna Well, there is a firewall running on the machine that filters everything except port 554 for some reason.

Comment: "The firewall on machine is disabled" Iptables -L report nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found,i use another ip class,so even avoid routing,firewall,etc
I simply change to virtualbox default host-only net(wich is 192.168.56.0/24) the ip of guest.
Now all ports are accessible,i still don't understand why rstp was open....

Comment: Dont forget to accept your answer to close the question!

Comment: I cann accept only tomorrow